# when the browser will close directly session would be expired

Tags: java, javascript, spring

I have such scenario . Where session would be expired hen I closed the browser directly.
Actually I wanna to log the values in DB. after session has been expired. I am invalidate the session in logout.jsp page. I need such code when browser window is cloesd, it will call logout.jsp and invalidate the session.. please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to really do it. Going to have to live with session end on the server.

Comment: But there are web pages, that loos all session data just after the window is closed.

Comment: You could try window.onunload = closeDown; (closeDown calls your logout.jsp file). But browser implementation is flaky at best.